# How to choose between "Subjunctive Mood" and "If - Adverbial clause of condition"?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I have below two sentences; how should I choose from these two in a conversation? It seems to me that  when we talk about the person (him), since he is not here at the time of the conversation, and thus that the fact I states cannot be a realistic one,  I should use "Subjunctive Mood", right? If so, what is the correct situation for the first sentence, namely the "If - Adverbial clause of condition", this one should be used in an achievable situation, right? But, every situation in which this one can be used is the fact, that the person "him" is not there at that moment which is contradictory to the usage of "If - Adverbial clause of condition".

> If he comes, he will tell me all the facts.

> If he came, he would tell me all the facts.

Comment: "But, every situation in which this one can be used is the fact, that the person "him" is not there at that moment which is contradictory to the usage of "If - Adverbial clause of condition": this sentence is not clear; you might want to review it and make sure it means what you intend to express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pertains to your first sentence, [here (British Council: Verbs in time clauses and 'if' clauses)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-in-time-clauses-and-if-clauses)  is an explanation of the principles to observe. It is a correct sentence, but the mood is not the subjunctive, it is the indicative (present). It doesn't matter whether the person you are talking about is absent or present.

The second is not correct from a certain point of view (mixed conditional) otherwise it is correct ([conditionals](https://preply.com/en/blog/2020/05/06/5-types-of-conditional-sentences-in-english/#scroll-to-heading-4)) . Here is the other form.

- If he had come, he **would  have told** me all the facts.

The difference between the two sentences—once corrected—is that the first relates to facts concerning the future, whereas for the second it is the past. You use "*would*" ([ref.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-and-would)) for the past.

---

*The new sentence, after the correction*

- If he came, he would tell me all the facts.

The subjunctive past (came) , according to some terminology, is used to state a hypothesis in the present and the near future (If he came now, or a little later…). The use of "would" is modal; it is meant to express a predictions or "refers to unreal or improbable present or future situations" ([ref.](https://www.grammaring.com/past-subjunctive)).

Comment: Sorry, the second one should be "If he came, he would tell me all the facts." which is the present tense of "Subjunctive Mood".

Comment: And for the first sentence, can we say like "If he is here now, he will tell me all the facts." which talking about the current situation. If this is correct in grammar, once we say like this, it means that person is not here at the time we speak which is contradictory to the fact, so the "Subjunctive Mood" should be used here instead, right? If so, what kind of situation that the preceding sentence can be used properly?

Comment: @YHSPY There are problems of point of view today: this use of the past is reckoned by all authorities as a subjunctive [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive): "the use of past tense to indicate unreality, as is done in English, is common crosslinguistically, and it is a mistake to confuse this correlation of form and function with the subjunctive mood." Paul Portner. Modality. Oxford Surveys in Semantics and Pragmatics. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2009.

Comment: @YHSPY No, this is not correct (If he is here now, he will tell me all the facts.); You must say "If he **were** here now, he **would** tell me all the facts."

Comment: @YHSPY "**came**" is not the present subjunctive (in any case) but the past. The present is "come". ([ref.](https://www.grammaring.com/past-subjunctive))

Comment: @YHSPY. You can say  "_If he is here now, he will tell me all the facts_"  if _here_ refers to a building. You are in one room of the building and you don't know if he is in another room. If you find him in that room or if he comes into your room, he will tell you the facts.